# How to fetch Google Calendar events as list in PHP?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API in my PHP application. In order to show notification on page I want the list of calendar events. Please help me with the code and libraries required for the same.

Comment: Welcome to stack we are not here to help you find the library's or the look in the documentation for the coding examples.  Please show us what you have tried and explain any issues you are having with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP implementation from the [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) docs:

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');

while(true) {
  foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    echo $event->getSummary();
  }
  $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
  if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```